# Error : React JS can not read the property

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, es6-module-loader

I have jsx class and i'm trying to display some contact data which retrive from API call but once i added **this.state.contacts.map** function it gives me an error, saying **TypeError: Cannot read property 'contacts' of null**

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { FetchDetails } from '../api_call/apis.js';

export default class FriendRight extends Component {

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      contacts: []
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    FetchDetails().initialize().then(function(results) {
      this.setState({
        contacts: results.contact
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render(){
    var items = this.state.contacts.map(function(item){
      return <a href="#" className="list-group-item ">
        <h4 className="list-group-item-heading">{item.fullName}</h4>
      </a>;
    });

    return(
      <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleClick}>Yahoo</button></li>
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default">Gmail</button></li>
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default" >Outlook</button></li>
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default" >Facebook</button></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Once i change code like below then the error got fixed. but then there is error,
    **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null**

```
 import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { FetchDetails } from '../api_call/apis.js';

export default class FriendRight extends Component {

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      contacts: []
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    FetchDetails().initialize().then(function(results) {
      this.setState({
        contacts: results.contact
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render(){
    if(this.getInitialState.length > 0){
      var items = this.state.contacts.map(function(item){
        return <a href="#" className="list-group-item ">
          <h4 className="list-group-item-heading">{item.fullName}</h4>
        </a>;
      });
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleClick}>Yahoo</button></li>
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default">Gmail</button></li>
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default" >Outlook</button></li>
          <li className="list-group-item"><button type="button" className="btn btn-default" >Facebook</button></li>
          <li>{this.getInitialState.length > 0 ? items : ""}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Just making sure: did you mean to do `contacts: results.contacts` in the `handleClick()`? I think you're just missing an `s`

Comment: No, the array which return from the api is like this.

contact: Array[65]
0: Object
email: "abcd@lilydigital.com"
fullName: "Nell Witowski"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object

Comment: @sameeradanthanarayana Try `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` Instead of `onClick={this.handleClick}`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `getInitialState()` in a es6 class. To fix this issue init the state on the `constructor()`.

Just like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      contacts: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { contacts } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {
          contacts.map((contact, key) => {
            return (<li key={ key }>{ contact.name }</li>);
          })
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Another way to handle this is a simple or clause in the `render()` function. Instead of `contacts.map(() => {` you can write `(contacts || []).map(() => {`.